# Qt and C++ QtPlugin - what kind of plugins can be handled?

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, multiplatform

I am about to create an application. I would like to keep it in modular architecture and to work on Linux, Mac and Windows. I want to use Qt library in general.

The most of the functionality of this application will be stored in plugins, which for some reasons is the best approach here. I am used to create plugins on C++. However I am considering to use Qt plugin management system.

My questions are:

1. Can this system be used to manage any kind of plugins? What I mean is that most (all I've run into) examples cover plugins regarding Qt styles and Qt elements, etc. No general plugin managemet like "Foo" plugin doing "hello world".
2. Are there any advantages of "manually created" pure C++ plugin system over Qt plugin system? Should I rather consider using pure C++ approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt offers a generic plugin system, and you can leverage it for whatever use you desire. The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/plugins-howto.html) has it covered.

Qt's low-level plugin api works on interface classes - classes with abstract virtual methods. A plugin implements such interface. The plugin loader gives you an instance of an interface-derived class that implements the interface.